# Site to Site VPN connection between TMG and AWS keeps dropping

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, ipsec, vpc

AWS VPC <==> TMG

I have an amazon VPC with a VPN IPsec VPN connection connected to a Microsoft Forefront TMG server as a customer gateway hosted on Server 2008 r2 SP1, the TMG application is also patched upto SP2 build 7.0.9193.500. The VPN tunnel will connect, stay connected for a short amount of time (roughly 5-10 minutes) then drop, it will connect and drop, connect and drop. I have ran a ping trace from a workstation on my LAN to the VPC and you can see very clearly the connection going up and down, however the AWS management consoles status is connected. I have no idea why and there aren't any logs in the server event viewer to shine any light on the issue.

I have also set the MTU to 1436 on the external network interface of the TMG box as recomended by Amazon as of this guide:

http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/VPC/latest/vpc-nag.pdf

Does anyone have any suggestion on what I could try to bring some stability to my VPN connection as its practically unusable at the moment.

Many thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be because AWS's VPC connection is limited to 2 total simultaneous IPSEC security associations.  Hence, if you're pinging from devices on different VLANs, it will drop a connection since it can only keep two active.  This happened to us and it appears to be a big limitation with a lame workaround for now.  For more details, check link below.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=144495&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

You have to have traffic on the VPN or Amazon VPN monitoring will drop the VPN. Try running a constant ping through the VPN. That should keep the connection alive.